# Style WPF DataGrid to show the red border when there are 0 items

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styles

I'm trying to style the `DataGrid` to show the red error border when there are no items in it's `ItemsSource` collection. I already have all the code written and working for the Triggers.

Here is what I tried:

```
<Style x:Key="WarningDataGrid" TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ocean:DataGridBehavior.HasWarning" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ocean:CheckBoxBehavior.Warning)}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But since I'm not using the validation framework all that happens is the red border replaces the DataGrid.

Do I need to start with the default style? If so where do I find it.

Comment: How about checking the `Items.Count` property and checking for a value of `0`?

Comment: I already have the code for what you are describing. I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, you want a red border **around** the datagrid when its empty, right?

Comment: Correct and I can achieve that with the code above except that the AdornedElementPlaceholder doesn't display anything, only the red border displays when it's empty.

Comment: Right, you're trying to use an `Adorner` which unless you're working with the `ValidationTemplate` you're not going to have.  I think you're probably over thinking this a litle bit, just wrap your data grid in a `Border` and use the trigger to change the `Border`'s visibility property.

Comment: If I wrap the DataGrid in a border and set the Border's visibility property the DataGrid also disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the whole template. Just set the `BorderBrush` :

```
<Style x:Key="WarningDataGrid" TargetType="DataGrid" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="ocean:DataGridBehavior.HasWarning" Value="true">
             <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="AliceBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ocean:CheckBoxBehavior.Warning)}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set ValidateOnErrors=True and ValidateOnExceptions=True in the Binding . I hope this will help.

Comment: I'm not using the Validation framework so this does not work. Thanks

Comment: Suppose you have DataGridTextColumn and it is bind to Type int property if you will enter string in that column It will work by setting ValidateOnExceptions=True.

Comment: I understand, however I am using custom validating code to set the properties and I am bound by company rules to use this code so therefore I can't use the validation framework and I setting the ValidateOnExceptions will not do anything in my case.